# How to get currently selected text from within electron desktop application?

Tags: node.js, electron, textselection

I am building a desktop application with [electron](http://electron.atom.io). As a part of its functionality I want to get text that is currently selected, when a particular event fires. This text can be any where - webpage, pdf, sublime etc.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Have you solved this? If not, does this tutorial offer a solution? - [JS-copy-selection-to-clipboard-tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/copytoclipboard.shtml)

Comment: This would work if the selected text is in the DOM. But if the if the selected text where on a text editor, this wouldn't work

Answer (score -2):

For text in the DOM,
you can use:

`selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()`

Comment: @Peshmerge answer the google search, not the actual question.